# net_connect.find_prompt() doesn't print the prompt, gives weird error in netmiko

Tags: python, automation, cisco, netmiko

I'm trying to print the switch prompt and then execute the comments in netmiko using the redispatch function.

netmiko gives a weird error in the output :

Portion of the code :

```
try:
    
    net_connect = Netmiko(**linux_jump_16)
    net_connect.global_delay_factor = 2
    print(net_connect.find_prompt())
    print(f"\n{'*'*10}Connected to the Jump host{'*'*10}")
    print(f"\n{'~'*50}\n2. Connecting to the Dest Router\n{'~'*50}")
    print(net_connect.find_prompt(), end='')
    net_connect.write_channel(f'ssh {username}@{coreswitchNCRS1}\n')
    time.sleep(3)
    output = net_connect.read_channel()
    #print(output)

    if 'Password' in output:
        net_connect.write_channel("yes" + '\n')
        print("     Received Password Prompt, Entering password    ")
        net_connect.write_channel(password + '\n')
        time.sleep(2)

        print(f"\n{'~'*50}\nDestination Device Prompt\n{'~'*50}\n")
        #print(net_connect.find_prompt())
        cmds = ['show ip int brief', 'show ip route', 'show users']
        
        redispatch(net_connect, **NetworkDevice)
        for cmd in cmds:
            print(f"\n{'~'*50}\nIn {net_connect.find_prompt()} Executing the Command: {cmd}\n{'~'*50}")
            #router_output = net_connect.send_command(cmd, expect_string=r'>|#|$', read_timeout=10)
            router_output = net_connect.send_command(cmd, read_timeout=20)
            print(router_output)
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Please full error traceback as text not image, and ensure code is reproducible (mre)

Comment: the screenshot which you see are the full traceback error... @OCa

Comment: I have noticed. The point is [do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)